# Angularfire: behavior of synchronized array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've been having issues with a synchronized arrays on angularfire. I'm on angularfire 1.1.3 with firebase 2.3.1.
I have a query

```
var arr = $firebaseArray(ref.limitToFirst(5));
```

and the behavior I've seen up until now is that when I call

```
arr.$remove(0)
```

the next object that would be returned by the query gets loaded into the synchronized array automatically. This essentially makes the array a sliding window over the query response - it always has the same number of elements.

Since last week, that behavior seems to have changed, and I get two different cases:

1: Either `arr` does get loaded with 5 items, but after calling `arr.$remove` five times, the array is empty - which would be normal behavior on a JavaScript array, but isn't what I'd been seeing before on an AngularFire synchronized array.

2: Or  `arr` is loaded but then disappears, i.e. in the code:

```
arr.$loaded(function(){
\\ break
})
```

If I break in the call back, `arr` does have five items, corresponding to data on Firebase, but at the end of the Angular digest loop, `arr` is an empty array.

**Demo:** **[This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wAQw4086h2MvySFTsDis?p=preview)** shows behavior 1

So my questions are:

- Was I relying on a behavior that was not officially part of the API?
- Has that behavior changed?
- What explains the last point (the firebase array having items on `$loaded` but then ending up empty?)

**Update**

It seems that behavior 2 happens after behavior 1 - more precisely: after getting to an empty synchronized array, if I reload the page, then I get a nonempty array in the callback of `arr.$loaded` but an empty array in the end. 
Could that mean that firebase itself gets "stuck"? 
I'll try to to reproduce that in the plunker.

Comment: This doesn't look related to AngularFire. And obviously, a change in behavior in AF would require at the very least a change in Angular or AF versions of the libs. My guess would be a regression in the SDK. A minimal repro without all the extra components (i.e. the smallest footprint possible that still reproduces the error) would be pretty helpful.

Comment: @Kato what do you think about the plunker - it shows the current behavior (nothing getting reloaded in the $firebaseArray). Is that behavior expected, or for a ```ref.limitToFirst(3).on(...)``` query should the array always have three elements (at least until all items at that locations have been seen)?

Comment: @AdrienF This does in fact look like a bug. We've got a fix queued up and will get it deployed. I'll update with an answer to this question once it's fully deployed.
Thanks for the report, and sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @GregSoltis thanks for the quick reply - do you have a rough estimate on timing (or a range)?

Comment: I can't guarantee it, but we're shooting for early next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Sorry for the inconvenience!